# What's a good example for a Haskell functor that is not an applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

Learning about functors in Haskell, e.g. `[Integer]` or `[] Integer`, I understand that the functor needs to define `fmap` (in the list example: `fmap = map`).
If I get it right, a functor can implement the *sequential application* `<*>` in order to become an *applicative functor*. This is why

```
[(1+), (2+)]
```

is a perfectly fine element of the list instance `[] Integer`. And an expression like

```
(+) <$> [1..10] <*> [101..110]
```

makes sence.

The examples for instances of `Functor` that I found were all *applicative functors*, too. I.e. there was a sensible definition of `<*>`. The typical examples for functors Maybe, [], Either e, Tree, e ->, Pair, (,) e, ... are usually applicative, as well (i.e. there is a sensible definition of `<*>`). From what I understand they are all monads, even!

I found `ZipList` as an example of an applicative functor that is not a monad ([for a reason](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-April/059088.html)).

Now is there a functor that is not an applicative functor and reasonably so?

Comment: The `((,) a)` functor, which you can think of as `(a ,)`

Comment: ....which is only an applicative functor if the (fixed) type a is a monoid. Thus, for example, ((,) Char) is not an applicative functor, even though ((,) String) is.

Comment: Perhaps two composed contravariant functors? This will yield a functor, but I guess an applicative won't be possible.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks This is not so. For example, `data F a = F ( (a -> Int) -> Int)` is a monad - a particular case of the continuation monad - but it is a composition of two contrafunctors. Another, less trivial example is `(a -> Int) -> a`, which is also a monad. Being monads, they are also applicatives. More generally, for any contrafunctor `C`, the functor `(C a) -> a` is a monad and thus also applicative.